# Capistrano 3, using upload! in a task in lib/capistrano/tasks

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, capistrano3

I'm using Capistrano 3 and I want to create my own task. So I created a file my_new_thing.rake in lib/capistrano/tasks and I can see the task when I run cap -T. But... some of the methods aren't available. When I try to use upload! I get

```
cap aborted!
NoMethodError: undefined method `upload!' for main:Object
```

But if I move the same task into config/deploy.rb then then upload! method is available.

So what's going on? How do I create new Capistrano tasks put them in separate file and have them work?

Answer (score 16):

I had the same problem, I created my own recipe in a separate file which I loaded in deploy but couldn't get upload! to work.

What fixed it for me was adding a role filter inside the task making my final recipe look something like this:

```
 namespace :figaro do      
   desc "Transfer Figaro's application.yml to shared/config"
   task :upload do
     on roles(:all) do
       upload! "config/application.yml", "#{shared_path}/config/application.yml"
     end
   end
 end
 before "deploy:check", "figaro:upload"
```

I hope that helps!

Comment: The on roles check was everything I needed. Thanks. +1

Comment: I had to add `execute "mkdir -p #{shared_path}/config"` just before the `upload!` line as that directory didn't exist on the server yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can create a folder `config/recipes` for your capistrano recipes if you want to keep them in separate files.

Use the `.rb` extension since this isnt a regular rake task.

In `config/deploy.rb` add this line

```
load File.expand_path('../recipes/my_new_thing.rb', __FILE__)
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to use the rake tasks then you will need to create a task in the deploy file which calls that rake tasks which is not that smart of a move. So as @Sharagoz suggested the best route will be to create your own recipe file and include that in.